# How do I send multiple reactions for discord.py in one line

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.command(name="test")
async def test(ctx):
     await ctx.message.add_reaction("""""")
```

This is what I currently have and it doesn't work I was wondering if anyone knows how to make this work so it sends the 3 reactions in one line. I don't want to have 3 awaits or have a for function for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list with reactions and then add it to the message.

**Here is a little example:**

```py
    reactions = ["1️⃣", "2️⃣", "3️⃣", "4️⃣"] # 4 reactions

    message = await ctx.send("Test")
    nreactions = 3 # Number of reactions you want to have
    for i in range(nreactions):
        await message.add_reaction(reactions[i]) # 3 reactions get added
```

This ends up being almost as much code as if you added all the reactions individually, but somewhat simplified. Putting everything into one line is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have seen multiple reactions been added at once.

Comment: I did just do a test on my pc and it looks like the bot that I was using was just slow on my phone

Comment: @DwarfmanDDH So what is going on now? The reactions will be added step-by-step